# Imported Hebrew vcf contacts come out gibberish

Tags: contacts, localization, import, hebrew

I just joined the Android community. I have been using a Nokia E72. I am a bilingual user (Hebrew/English). I have succeeded in importing my address book 838 contacts with the help of this blog http://myhtcdesire.com/tutorials/how-to-transfer-contacts-from-a-nokia-symbian-phone-to-htc-desire

My Android OS came with Hebrew/English pre-installed. The problem is that in the imported address book all of the Hebrew in contacts show as gibberish.

I tried switching back and forth the default language, but that made no difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found the solution here http://iandroid.co.il/forum/topic1999.html

Comment: If it's the answer you were looking for, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an encoding problem.  Have you tried importing the .vcf into Google Contacts (on the web) and then syncing your phone with your Google account contacts?  That might provide better results; Android doesn't play nice with multiple languages right now.

Comment: What if I do not have internet connection nor wifi on my Android? what then? how the google contacts can be of any help what so ever?

Comment: @Miki800 I honestly wouldn't consider a phone without Wi-Fi a smartphone. If you're in that situation, however, consider asking your own question -- most everyone has Wi-Fi so in the absence of evidence otherwise, those considerations aren't relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the steps mentioned [here](http://www.iminfo.in/post/how-to-transfer-contacts-from-nokia-symbian-s40-to-android).

It's using .vcf technique only. I had to transfer Nokia C3 contacts to Sony Xperia and it worked for me.

> 1. Create a backup file in your nokia phone.
> 2. For that go to **Menu > Settings > Sync and backup > Create Backup**
> 3. Select only "Contacts" for backup.
> 4. It will create a backup file at a location you specified.
> 5. Copy that backup file in your PC.
> 6. Rename its extension to ".zip" or ".rar" (make sure to uncheck "Hide extensions for known types")
> 7. Then extract this file. It will extract all your contacts in root folder named "32" in ".vcf" format.
> 8. Copy this folder into your memory card
> 9. Then go to "Contacts" in your android phone. press on the 3 grey dots on the upper or bottom right of the screen.
> 10. Select Import from the list. Next, select Import from > SD Card / external memory.
> 11. It will search for ".vcf" files and popup you the choice to import specific files or all (select "Import all vCard files" to
>       import all contacts)
> 12. Wait for a while and its done.